# Explaining how to use classes with SASS to a Python thinker

Tags: python, html, css, sass

I am coming from object-oriented Python-land and need help with a basic question as I learn SASS (+compass/susy) and CSS. Globally, I am struggling to understand how to relate classes and variables as I understand it in Python.

I have a navigation bar and want all `h1` tags in the navbar to be bold, but all `h1` tags in the body of the html doc to be blue. How would I structure my screen.scss file to reflect what I am trying to do?

To make it a little more complicated, let's say I have more tags, like an `h2` tag that I want to do the same thing with as well (except this time I want `h2` to be italic and red respectively). In this case, can I start using a class selector instead of an id? Is there a way to *nest* my sass file such that `h1` and `h2` tags are only modified if they are under `class='navbar'`? In python, I would say something like:

```
class navbar
    h1 = make it bold
    h2 = make it italic

h1 = make it blue
h2 = make it red
```

In SASS-land, how would you structure your screen.sass file such that I can just assign each html tag (`<htmltag class='navbar'>` and everything behaves appropriately? Or, if there is a better way to do this with a ton of elements, I am open to that as well.

Thank you.

Comment: the word `class` in (S)CSS (or really, HTML) has a different meaning to that in python. Don't attempt to match them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need classes or variables for your use case. Say you have a HTML document like this (notice that we're using a [`nav`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nav) element for navigation, so there's no need for a `navbar` class):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>An example document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <h1>A navigation heading</h1>
      <h2>A subheading</h2>
      <!-- etc. -->
    </nav>
    <main>
      <h1>A general heading</h1>
      <h2>A subheading</h2>
      <!-- etc. -->
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

... then to get all of the effects you ask about in your question, the following SASS is enough:

```sass
nav
  h1
    font-weight: bold
  h2
    font-style: italic

main
  h1
    color: blue
  h2
    color: red
```

I'm assuming from the way you word your question that when you say 'the body of the html' document, you're referring to some 'main' content which is *separate* from that in the navbar, rather than everything in the `body` element (which would *include* the navbar). If that assumption is wrong and you do indeed want everything to be coloured, but only navbar headings emboldened/italicized, you'd do this:

```
nav
  h1
    font-weight: bold
  h2
    font-style: italic

h1
  color: blue

h2
  color: red
```

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudo-code is almost exactly the same as SASS:

```
.navbar
    h1
        font-weight: bold
    h2
        font-style: italic
body
    h1
        color: blue
    h2
        color: red
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer is kinda generic, but I found your question also generic. I'll suggest to read more about OOCSS, [here](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki) or [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/) for example. It's also a good idea to check the Brad's [Atomic design](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/). I don't think that preprocessor matter so much. It's more like a conceptual problem.